# In typescript, in a typed function argument, optional properties are ignored by intellisense. Why?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a router initialiser with a nice typed DX in typescript.

My goal is to allow the developer to define a path and params types for each route's params at each level. My example is truncated, in order to better demonstrate my problem.

Each route node looks like:

```
export type RouteArgs<TProps extends t.Props> =
{
  path: string;
  type?: TProps;
};
```

In order to preserve typing, but enforce type constraints, I create a 'builder' function:

```
export type RoutesArgs = {
  [key: string]: RouteArgs<{}>;
};

interface RoutesFn {
  <TRoutesArgs extends RoutesArgs>(args: TRoutesArgs): TRoutesArgs;
}

export const routes: RoutesFn = args => args;
```

The `routes` function's only purpose is to enforce typing of the arguments, and return the actual type inferred from the arguments. It is used like this:

```
const r = routes({
  FOO: {
    // Intellisense kicks in here...
  },
});
```

When intellisense kicks in for the `FOO` object, it suggests both `path` and `type` properties. `path` is required, so I add path, and hit intellisense again.

```
const r = routes({
  FOO: {
    path: '/foo',
    // Now, intellisense is empty...
  },
});
```

Instead of recommending just `type`, as expected, it now doesn't suggest anything.

In fact, it also allows me to add 'garbage' properties...

```
const r = routes({
  FOO: {
    path: '/foo',
    // Ideally, it would complain about the following...
    rubbish: 1234
  },
});
```

I fear I am running up against a feature of typescript's structural typing. I think it sees `path` as satisfied and then gives up matching the rest.

Part of the charm of this approach is that it's just an object literal and I don't have to instantiate classes for each route node, so I'd like to avoid having to use classes.

Is there any way to convince typescript to enforce nominal typing in this kind of scenario without resorting to a pass-through function for each route?

Comment: I could work on trying to forbid extra keys, but I can't reproduce your lack of IntelliSense: see [IDE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAXJBvJEAeMD2ATmigJ4zIAKBeMUSAvBgL5JMCwAUJzvkamcgBKeAK4oIAQQIBzKAB4AKlRp0c44ABM6KAHTLaAPgackGE6aRwUACwBcSKCgIBLYNIDc506XIB+e0rUtJ4cpkwh3LiExAJIwmLQUrIMZqFIANoA1hAk9o4ubgC69vHiSfLoTAYh4ZycruIEAGYIQqLiUABiwKmmiqWJMqrY6lpx7YOyBgAUIEMBA1DlAJQLE0tDNXUcPNFI8HjAjkjUCVAl690pc8n0RjdQERwHR2gEKacd0+jmnQDyf3sPzSpisdiQAHIAPRNPB4CEAGi8SChUKQAElgOIADbY5xQCBHZBQETSaTQFB0ABEPggVKQ1ggBAg5iYSI4TGW7iAA) and [img](https://i.imgur.com/Nzh0ceX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem you're having with IntelliSense.

As for forbidding extra properties, you're right that the structural type system allows for such extra properties by default.  (Specifically it's required by `interface` and `class` extension... if adding properties to a subclass or an interface extension resulted in incompatibility with the superclass or parent interface, inheritance and subtyping would be unwieldy.)  Object types in TypeScript are generally not treated as "[exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)".  I say "generally" because the language has carved out an exception for object literals in certain situations with [excess property checking](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  In your case this does not apply, though, because the object literal is of a generic type that *extends* an object type, and since extensions may have extra properties, you're back where you started.

So TypeScript doesn't support exact types *directly*.  But you can [indirectly describe such types via generic type constraints](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671).  For example:

```
type Exactly<T, C> = T & { [K in Exclude<keyof C, keyof T>]: never };

interface RoutesFn {
  <T extends RoutesArgs>(args: T & { [K in keyof T]: Exactly<RouteArgs<{}>, T[K]> }): T;
}
```

The `Exactly<T, C>` generic type takes a type `T` and a *candidate* type `C`, and returns a new type which is compatible with `C` if and only if it an "exact" match for `T`.  If `C` contains any extra properties, these extra properties get transformed into type `never`.

Then the `RoutesFn` type is similar to before, except that the `args` parameter is checked against both your constrained generic `T` (I've shortened it from `TRoutesArgs`) *and* a version where each property of `T` has been checked against an exact version of `RouteArgs<{}>`.

Let's see it work:

```
const r = routes({
  FOO: {
    path: '/foo',
    type: { f: 1 },
    rubbish: 1 // error!
    //~~~~~ <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
  },
  BAR: {
    path: '/bar',
  }
});
```

So that's good; you now get an error on extra properties without losing the type inference.  There's also still IntelliSense, at least in my IDE (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXv1Y.png)).

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Exactly, bends my mind the kind of things that are possible with typescript.

Regarding the intellisense... I'm starting to wonder if my IDE/machine is at fault here, because in the web IDE of typescript playground, intellisense behaves as expected, but on my machine, in VSCode it doesn't. Also I get disappointing intellisense performance even in small projects. Also, often type resolution seems to die, take ages to update or stops half-way, as if ts language server runs out of memory or gives up. Not sure what I can do to debug this, though... any advice?